# Is a quotient of ring of polynomials Cohen-Macaulay?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $R = \mathbb{R}[x_1 , \ldots , x_n]$ be a polynomial ring and $I \subset R$ be a principal ideal with $I = \langle f \rangle$. I know that $R$ is a CM ring. So my question is that:

1. Is the quotient ring $R/I$ also CM for any $I \subset R$ ?
2. If $R/I$ is CM, then the quotient $R/I^2$ is also CM where $I^2 = \langle f^2 \rangle$ ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to both (1) and (2) is yes. More generally we have the following:

> **Proposition.** If $R$ is any CM domain with principal ideal $I$, then $R/I$ is CM.

*Proof.* First recall the definition for (non-local) CM rings, from [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00N7):

**Definition 10.103.6.** A Noetherian ring $R$ is called *Cohen-Macaulay* if all its local rings are Cohen-Macaulay.

and a fact from the Wikipedia page [Cohen-Macaulay ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Macaulay_ring#Properties):

($\bullet$) For a non-zero-divisor $u$ in the maximal ideal of a Noetherian local ring $R$, $R$ is Cohen–Macaulay if and only if $R/(u)$ is Cohen–Macaulay.

For $\mathfrak p \in \operatorname{Spec}R$ we know $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is CM and $I_\mathfrak p$ is principal. By ($\bullet$), we find that for all $\mathfrak p \supset I$  the quotient $R_{\mathfrak p}/I_\mathfrak p$ is CM. Such $\mathfrak p$ correspond precisely to the prime ideals $\bar{\mathfrak p}$ of $R/I$. Finally since $(R/I)_{\bar{\mathfrak p}} = R_{\mathfrak p}/I_{\mathfrak p}$, the proposition follows. $\square$